# Translate around a square

Tags: java, debugging

I have a car game that has a square donut as a race course. I want to make some dummy cars that will simply go around this square course and am running into some issues on the final turn that the AI cars have to make.

Below I'm also adding a basic picture showing the concept of the race course I have. The cars are starting near the origin, translating in the y direction, then translating in the x direction, followed by another translation in the y going up the strip and then one last turn in the x direction.

```
double velX = 2;
double vely = 2;
if (positionx < 14 && positiony < 60){ //move straight down the first strip
    vely += vely;
    velx = 0;
}
if (positiony > 65){ //make the first turn and move x units
    gl.glRotated(90, 0, 1, 0);
    velx += velx;
    vely = 0;
}
if (positionx > 20){ //make the next turn and go down the next strip
    gl.glRotated(180, 0, 1, 0);
    vely = 2;
    velx = 0;
    vely -= vely + 1;
}
if (positiony < -68){ //Here is where I am running into my error. I turn but get stuck
    gl.glRotated(-270, 0, 1, 0);
    vely = 0;
    velx += velx -1;
}
positionx += velx;
positiony += vely;
```

[image]

Comment: Are your rotation angles correct? Are you sure it must be -270 instead of 270?

Comment: You should use `if else` not just `if`. One of the `if` is in conflict with another `if`. Let me see if I can find which. But it seems better approach to have a coherent conditional structure.

Comment: @Verhaeren I was hoping it wasn't that issue. I currently don't see which one is breaking the others. In theory they should all make the car go perfectly in a square

Comment: You could check what is the value of your coordinates variables when you do the last turn `(-270, 0, 1, 0)` to see if they are meeting the cryteria in another `if` block.

Comment: EDIT: I think my problem is between the first and last if condition since positiony is true for both. I'm not sure what I could do though to fix this.

Comment: Do this: `if (positionx < 14 && positiony < 60){ [code] } else { [rest of the code] }`.

Comment: As @Jesper already hinted, you only have 3 different rotations, since 90 and -270 are the same angle.

Answer (score 0):

The error that causes you to get stuck occurs at position 20,-69 where:

```
if (positiony < -68){ //Here is where I am running into my error. I turn but get stuck
    gl.glRotated(-270, 0, 1, 0);
    vely = 0;
    velx += velx -1;
}
```

`velx` has been initialized to *2*; the `velx += velx -1` makes it *3*, letting the car bounce back to position 23,-69 and repeat. If you changed the `velx += velx -1` to just `velx = -2`, the car would move on.